# WSO2 ESB Convert 70MB JSON payload to XML

Tags: wso2-esb

Can WSO2 ESB convert 70MB json payload to xml with passthrough transport?

I tried but getting JVM heap running out of memory (2GB heap size).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Mabye you can try convert this JSON in JAVA code and use it as Class mediator, like this https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Class+Mediator